# Representations of the orthogonal group O(n) vs representations of the special orthogonal group SO(n), over an arbitrary field

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $O(n)$ and $SO(n)$ denote the split orthogonal linear algebraic group and its special subgroup, over some fixed field of characteristic not two. 
I am looking for a reference that explains how to describe the simple (finite-dimensional) representations of $O(n)$ in terms of the simple representations of $SO(n)$.

The relation between the complex representations of the corresponding compact Lie groups is explained in section VI.7 of  Bröcker and tom Dieck’s *Representations of Compact Lie Groups*.  I believe the key statements made there also hold in the above algebraic situation,  and I have worked this out in a fair amount of detail,  but I am currently unwilling to believe that this has not already been done somewhere in the literature.
Roughly, these statements are as follows:

- When $n$ is odd, $O(n)$ is a direct product of $SO(n)$ with $\mathbb Z/2$. Thus, every simple $SO(n)$-representation can be lifted to two distinct $O(n)$-representations, and every $O(n)$-representation arises in this way. (See also [this question regarding simple representations of products](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137909).)
- When $n$ is even, $O(n)$ is only a semi-direct product of $SO(n)$ with $\mathbb Z/2$.  In this case, only some simple $SO(n)$-representations can be lifted. Those that can be lifted can again be lifted to two distinct $O(n)$-representations.  The remaining simple $SO(n)$-representations occur in pairs whose direct sum can be lifted to a unique simple $O(n)$-representation.  All simple $O(n)$-representations arise in either of these ways.

Of course, in this question I am mainly interested in references concerning the case when $n$ is even.

Comment: For the time being, the “fair amount of detail” I am referring to may be found in Proposition 3.18 and in Section 4.2 of [arXiv:1308.0796](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0796).

Comment: For $k=\mathbb C$, it's explained in Section 5.5.5 of Goodman-Wallach's book "Symmetry, represenations, and invariants".

Comment: As long as the characteristic of the field of definition is *good* (not 2), as you assume, it doesn't seem to matter over which field the groups are defined and split.   Representations will be studied over an algebraically closed field, where for $n$ even the methods will rely on standard induction/restriction.   Older group representation texts for physicists probably cover orthogonal groups, while Jantzen's book on algebraic groups may be overkill.

Comment: P.S. As pointed out in a comment, the Springer GTM 255 by Goodman-Wallach is likely to be a reliable source for your purpose.   I don't have that 2009 edition, but the first edition titled *Representations and Invariants of the Classical Groups* (Cambridge, 1998)  has the relevant material in sections 5.2.2 and 10.2.5.

Comment: @JimHumphreys: I’m not sure what you mean by “representations will be studied over an algebraically closed field”—I want the representations to be defined over the same field as the group itself.  Do I need to make this more precise in the question?

Comment: @JimHumphreys: Serre's [_Groupes de Grothendieck des schémas en groupes réductifs déployés_](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=231831) and/or [Jantzen](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2015057) tell me that for a _split reductive_ group scheme like SO(n), the simple representations defined over k remain simple over the algebraic closure, and conversely all simple representations over the algebraic closure are already defined over k.  But in general, this is not true, and I don't think either of Serre or Jantzen use the term “reductive” to include non-connected groups like O(n).